# What's mean in this SWIFT statement?

Tags: ios, swift, operators

```
/// Image handler, used when setting up an image using some sort of process.
open var imageHandler: ((UIImageView)->Bool)?
/// The image view.
fileprivate var imageView: UIImageView!
...
let showImage = imageHandler?(imageView) ?? false
```

What's mean about this statement

```
let showImage = imageHandler?(imageView) ?? false
```

So many ? make me crazy.

Comment: Look up “optional chaining” and “nil-coalescing operator” ...

Comment: I'm assuming your just asking how to make it cleaner, not how it works?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

“imageHandler?(imageView)” will return some value and that value will be assigned to showImage. If it returns nil than false will get assign to showImage.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation:**

```
let showImage = imageHandler?(imageView) ?? false
```

First thing is first, `imageHandler` is a code block, which is declared to take an `UIImageView` and the whole `imageHandler` could be just `nil`.

So the first `?` in the statement

```
imageHandler?(imageView)
```

Just fine an simple optional chaining.

Secondly the `imageHandler` returns a `BOOL`. But the `imageHandler` itself is optional. So incase of `imageHandler` itself is `nil`, what should be the value to be assigned in `showImage`. So this code decide that `false` using nil-coalescing.

You could just use optional unwrapping as follows

```
var showImage = false
if let result = imageHandler?(imageView) {
    showImage = result
}
```

So i think you got everything you want to know.

Answer (score 3):

If the optional `imageHandler` is set, the call to it succeeds and the value returned is unwrapped and assigned to `showImage`. Otherwise, `showImage` is set to false.

Optional Chaining:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html

Nil-coalescing operator:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html

Answer (score 0):

Its an Optional chaining Statemen 
this statement is equal to following...

```
if imageView != nil {
   showImage = true
}
else {
    showImage = false
}
```

In optional chaining we write it like your example

Comment: Does it mean?
if imageView != nil {
   imageHandler(imageView)
   showImage = true
}
else {
    showImage = false
}

Comment: no actually what imageHandler is doing it is checking for nil if image imageHandler finds imageView as nil it will return false else imageHandler will return true as optional now what is optional it is another topic

Comment: imageHandler actually working same as example code i have given, but  open var imageHandler: ((UIImageView)->Bool)?  is return for reusability and to shorten the code

Answer (score 0):

I might suggestion a default implementation for imageHandler, especally if you are going to use that function more then once. Something like this is cleaner IMHO:

```
// Image handler, used when setting up an image using some sort of process.
var imageHandler: ((UIImageView)->Bool) = { _ in return false }

// The image view.
fileprivate var imageView: UIImageView!

// Checking if should show image
let showImage = imageHandler(imageView)
```

You can even change `{ _ in return false }` to `{ _ in false }`, but I'm not sure if that is worth the lack of readability for a little shorter of a line.

If you can't make your imageHandler an optional you could unwrap it step by step as suggested by other people. But I don't think your initial showImage declaration is to gross. Its going to be easier to read then 4 lines of unwrapping.